# can i get a new suspension kit for a older mongoose XR-75

Tags: suspension, full-suspension

I've searched but I can't find anything online. Is there a store I can go to or something?

Comment: Politely - this bike is a walmart BSO, which is also an amazon BSO in these modern days.  https://www.amazon.com/mongoose-xr-75-dual-suspension-mens/dp/b004qlogp4   The design is at least 12 years old, and the whole bike retails for barely over $100 US.   Its not worth spending any money on a bike like this.    Rememer also that bikes aren't cars, and you don't need a thing specifically for your make and model.  Instead you look at the dimensions and standards.  Your other option is to buy another similar-age bike and assemble the good bits.  Check if you have a Bike Co-operative in your area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [bso](/questions/tagged/bso). You won't find replacement parts that aren't maintenance items (brakes, tires, tubes, freewheels, etc.), since they will exceed the cost of the bike (particularly big things, like suspension or wheels). The suspensions on these bikes are mainly for aesthetics, not for actually taking hits in mountain biking (full suspension bikes are jolly expensive; front suspension only bikes are not that much -- few hundred bucks to start for decent basics, cheaper on used market).

You're better off getting a new bike if you need suspension, or living with the suspension as is.